# Bluetooth connection refused with secure rfcomm socket (works with insecure)

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

Right now I'm creating an android app that is communicating with some medical devices via bluetooth in order to display examination results on smartphone and I have this strange problem:

**createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)** works and connects phone to devices on android 2.1 - 3.x (Galaxy SI, Galaxy SII and couple other tablets) but it **DOES NOT** work on android 4.x (Galaxy SIII, Galaxy Trend). I'm receiving Connection refused error.
However, insecure connection **createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)** works fine for all of these versions except of course 2.1 because insecure connection was introduced in API level 10.

Anyone has any idea why is this happening this way? Is it hardware/driver related or I'm just doing something wrong. And yes, I have to support android 2.1.

Comment: HI I was looking for insecure connection between android Bluetooth device and RFID Bluetooth device,so please share source code if you have or guide me how to do.

Answer (score 2):

Google replaced Android's bluetooth code with a different version in Android 4.2. This removed support for L2CAP sockets and other features. This is probably the reason you're seeing the differences. I use **createInsurecureRfcommSocket**() on all versions of Android (2.3 and above) and it seems to work fine. Instead of connecting based on the service record, I search for specific bluetooth device names in the paired devices list and then connect to that address on channel 1.

Here is a simplified view of the code (not showing the try/catches):

```
 BluetoothDevice btDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(btTargetAddress);
 m = btDevice.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
 mSocket = (BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(btDevice, 1);
```